# Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'int' to 'int'

Tags: java

не пойму почему не работает instanceof, мне нужно сделать проверку на тип переменной, выводит Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'int' to 'int'

```
            try {
                int[] numbers;
                numbers = new int [3];

                System.out.println("Введите числа");
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                       numbers[i]=scanner.nextInt();
                

                    if(!(numbers[i] instanceof  int)){
                        throw new Exception1("Ошибка: Не подходящий тип данных",numbers[i]);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Оператор instanceof не работает с примитивными типами, только со ссылочными. Если ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы проверить ввод пользователя, то лучше воспользуйтесь более распространённым решением:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int[] numbers;
numbers = new int[3];

System.out.println("Введите числа");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    } else {
        scanner.next();
        //Добавьте свой код, если введён не int
    }

}

for (int i : numbers) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вдруг почему-то надо динамически проверить примитивный тип элемента массива, то можно использовать `Class`:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3};
boolean isInstance = numbers.getClass().getComponentType() == Integer.TYPE;
System.out.println(isInstance);
```

Но, скорее всего, здесь вообще ничего проверять в массиве не нужно. Проверки нужны, если массив был бы, например, `Object[]`, а по типу элемента необходимо делать те или иные действия. Если значение попало в массив `int[]`, то оно уже заведомо `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Самым лучшим аналогом будет являться метод `isInstance()`:

```
if (!Integer.class.isInstance(numbers[i]))
    throw new Exception1("Ошибка: Не подходящий тип данных",numbers[i]);
```